# I need get the file by windows handle(HWND)， how can i do？

Tags: c++, windows, hook

I need to make a security software to restrict the user's copy and paste In Windows. so i use C++ API HOOK to HOOK Clipboard. when some process want to getclipboarddata, i can get the window handle that setclipboarddata Recently。
But now i need to get the file info just like file path in the window that setclipboard data。 how can i do？
for example, notepad process open an file "C:\1.txt" and draw a window to show
txt data。i can get the window handle， how can i get the txt file path。

Comment: You probably need to read [help] and [mcve].

Comment: This question seems based on the flawed assumption that there is exactly one file for a `HWND`. This is untrue. Explorer.EXE shows many files in its main windows, while most dialogs do not display any files.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this:

```
DWORD proc_id;
TCHAR path[MAX_PATH];

GetWindowThreadProcessId(wnd, &proc_id);
HANDLE proc_handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, FALSE, proc_id);
GetProcessImageFileName(proc_handle, path, MAX_PATH);
CloseHandle(proc_handle);
```

Comment: If you are trying to get the path to the EXE for the process, you don't need `EnumProcessModules()`, just pass NULL to the `hModule` parameter of `GetModuleFileNameEx()`. Note, however, the documentation says: "*To retrieve the name of the main executable module **for a remote process**, use the `GetProcessImageFileName` or `QueryFullProcessImageName` function. **This is more efficient and more reliable** than calling the `GetModuleFileNameEx` function with a NULL module handle.*"

Comment: @RemyLebeau, thanks. I've corrected the answer.

Comment: note that `GetProcessImageFileName()` (and `QueryFullProcessImageName()`, too) requires only `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` rights. Don't request more permissions than you actually need

Comment: sorry， i do not need EXE file path。For example，the notepad.exe open a file "C:\1.txt" . i need txt file path